# Select multiple rows in UIPickerView only when tapped (not when scrolling to a row)

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to select multiple rows on a UIPickerView exactly like what is happening over here: 
[This is the default functionality I'm getting on Safari on an iPhone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzWlM.jpg)

As you can see, you're able to select multiple rows (and get visual cues). The selection is happening after I tap on the row, not when I scroll to it. Seeing as this is being done on Safari on the iPhone by default, I thought there would be similar functionality built into UIPickerViews in Xcode/Swift, but there doesn't seem to be. I've tried to find an answer online to no avail. There doesn't seem to be any simple implementation to get this kind of functionality.

So I guess my question is: Is there a simple way to implement this that I'm just not aware of? If not, if there's a framework for this kind of thing or something.

Comment: What is your actual question? You seem to already know that this can't be done with `UIPickerView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done with UIPickerView.
Either build you own with UITableView or use something like [RSSelectionMenu](https://github.com/rushisangani/RSSelectionMenu)